# Only one view controller orientation issue when going back to pervious view controller in ios 7

Tags: ios7, orientation

In my app we need only one view controller would be in all orientation mode other view controllers will be portrait mode only.

I am using below code and it's working perfectly but when coming back to pervious view controller it's not rotating in portrait mode when I am coming from Landscape mode.

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
  // Get topmost/visible view controller
  UIViewController *currentViewController = [self topViewController];

  // Check whether it implements a dummy methods called canRotate
  if ([currentViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(canRotate)]) {
      // Unlock landscape view orientations for this view controller
      return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
  }

  // Only allow portrait (standard behaviour)
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIViewController*)topViewController {
  return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
}

- (UIViewController*)topViewControllerWithRootViewController:(UIViewController*)rootViewController {
  if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {
    UITabBarController* tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)rootViewController;
    return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:tabBarController.selectedViewController];
  } else if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
    UINavigationController* navigationController = (UINavigationController*)rootViewController;
    return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:navigationController.visibleViewController];
  } else if (rootViewController.presentedViewController) {
    UIViewController* presentedViewController = rootViewController.presentedViewController;
    return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:presentedViewController];
  } else {
    return rootViewController;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been working against the same issue. The orientation can be forced back to its normal configuration by adding an adjustment in viewWillAppear of the controller you are going back to:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```